# Ffmpeg : Bitstream not supported by this decoder

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, webrtc, mediarecorder

I'm trying to create a livestream web app using NodeJS. The code I currently have emits a raw (webm format) binary stream from the webcam on the client using socket IO and the node server receives this raw data. Using fluent-ffmpeg, I want to encode this binary stream into mpegts and send it to an RTMP server in **real time**, without creating any intermediary files. However when trying to convert the blobs in ffmpeg I get the following error :

```
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[NULL @ 000001b15e67bd80] Invalid sync code 61f192.
[libvpx @ 000001b15e6c5000] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
```

My relevant frontend client code :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
    video_show(stream);//only show locally, not remotely

    socket.emit('config_rtmpDestination',url);
    socket.emit('start','start');
    var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264'};

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    mediaRecorder.start(2000);

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
        stream.stop();
    }

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        //var arraybuffer = Uint8Array.from(e.data).buffer;
        socket.emit("binarystream", blob);
        //chunks.push(e.data);
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
    show_output('Local getUserMedia ERROR:'+err);
});
```

Relevant NodeJS server code :

```
socket.on('binarystream',function(m){
    feedStream(m);
});

socket.on('start',function(m){
    ...
    var ops=[
        '-vcodec', socket._vcodec,'-i','-',
        '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'veryfast', '-tune', 'zerolatency',
        '-an', '-bufsize', '1000',
        '-f', 'mpegts', socket._rtmpDestination
    ];
    ffmpeg_process=spawn('ffmpeg', ops);
    feedStream=function(data){
        ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(data);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the raw binary stream?

Comment: @szatmary the format is in webm. I use these options  in the mediaRecorder : var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264'};

Comment: looking at "[libvpx @ 000001b15e6c5000] Failed to decode frame" libvpx should not be called. I am guessing that ffmpeg assumes that your receiving stream is VP8 or VP9.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is bumping to this issue.. try replacing `libvpx` with `libvpx-vp9` or to the more advanced version of libvpx

Comment: This did the trick for me while converting a webm to a webp. Cheers!